# jquery fancybox, does not open video from local source

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

i am using fancybox for playing a video using jquery. but it is not working.. if i provide url from youtube or from any other site, it works perfectly. but when i give href from local host , i does not work . here is my code .

```
$.fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',
            'autoScale': true,
            'transitionIn': 'fade',
            'transitionOut': 'fade',
            'href': 'http://localhost/projects/flippingbook/video/video.mp4',
            helpers : {
                media : {}
            }
        });
```

Comment: where do you host your website? I think it should be on the same domain

Comment: i am working on localhost

Comment: can you post your fiddle?

Comment: As it was already pointed out, you need a video player for your self-hosted videos. The reason it works with youtube is because YT provides already an embedded player so you don't have to provide a video player of your own (you could play youtube videos with your self-hosted video player though.)

Answer (score 3):

First of all you need to understand what `Fancybox` does. `Fancybox plugin` can open `HTML` content (or page) into a popup `modal`. Here in your code what you are doing is, you are passing the URL of a `mp4` file, which is wrong.

What you need to do is to create a `HTML` page where your video gets played (using some video player) and pass the URL of that page to `Fancybox` initialization.

Comment: `you are passing the URL of a mp4 file, which is wrong` well, it's not necessarily wrong since you can build the fancybox content to call a player and then attach the `href` to it. Additionally, you (may to but) don't have to create a html page since you can show the video inline within the same page (notice I didn't mean hidden `inline` content)

Answer (score 0):

you can use iframe option of fancybox try using like this.

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="learn android.mp4">Iframe</a>
```

and in the head section add

```
<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/fancybox/lib/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox main JS and CSS files -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.5"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" media="screen" />

<!-- Add Button helper (this is optional) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>

<!-- Add Thumbnail helper (this is optional) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>

<!-- Add Media helper (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8080/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*
         *  Simple image gallery. Uses default settings
         */

        $('.fancybox').fancybox();

        /*
         *  Different effects
         */

        // Change title type, overlay closing speed
        $(".fancybox-effects-a").fancybox({
            helpers: {
                title : {
                    type : 'outside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    speedOut : 0
                }
            }
        });

        // Disable opening and closing animations, change title type
        $(".fancybox-effects-b").fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'over'
                }
            }
        });

        // Set custom style, close if clicked, change title type and overlay color
        $(".fancybox-effects-c").fancybox({
            wrapCSS    : 'fancybox-custom',
            closeClick : true,

            openEffect : 'none',

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    css : {
                        'background' : 'rgba(238,238,238,0.85)'
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Remove padding, set opening and closing animations, close if clicked and disable overlay
        $(".fancybox-effects-d").fancybox({
            padding: 0,

            openEffect : 'elastic',
            openSpeed  : 150,

            closeEffect : 'elastic',
            closeSpeed  : 150,

            closeClick : true,

            helpers : {
                overlay : null
            }
        });

        /*
         *  Button helper. Disable animations, hide close button, change title type and content
         */

        $('.fancybox-buttons').fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'none',

            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,

            helpers : {
                title : {
                    type : 'inside'
                },
                buttons : {}
            },

            afterLoad : function() {
                this.title = 'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + (this.title ? ' - ' + this.title : '');
            }
        });


        /*
         *  Thumbnail helper. Disable animations, hide close button, arrows and slide to next gallery item if clicked
         */

        $('.fancybox-thumbs').fancybox({
            prevEffect : 'none',
            nextEffect : 'none',

            closeBtn  : false,
            arrows    : false,
            nextClick : true,

            helpers : {
                thumbs : {
                    width  : 50,
                    height : 50
                }
            }
        });

        /*
         *  Media helper. Group items, disable animations, hide arrows, enable media and button helpers.
        */
        $('.fancybox-media')
            .attr('rel', 'media-gallery')
            .fancybox({
                openEffect : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',
                prevEffect : 'none',
                nextEffect : 'none',

                arrows : false,
                helpers : {
                    media : {},
                    buttons : {}
                }
            });

        /*
         *  Open manually
         */

        $("#fancybox-manual-a").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open('1_b.jpg');
        });

        $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open({
                href : 'iframe.html',
                type : 'iframe',
                padding : 5
            });
        });

        $("#fancybox-manual-c").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open([
                {
                    href : '1_b.jpg',
                    title : 'My title'
                }, {
                    href : '2_b.jpg',
                    title : '2nd title'
                }, {
                    href : '3_b.jpg'
                }
            ], {
                helpers : {
                    thumbs : {
                        width: 75,
                        height: 50
                    }
                }
            });
        });


    });
</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .fancybox-custom .fancybox-skin {
        box-shadow: 0 0 50px #222;
    }

    body {
        max-width: 700px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
</style>
```

Hope this will work for you. I have attached fancybox files according to my local host server modify it according to your project